# What is causing the error in the formula =NETWORKDAYS.INTL(JANEIRO!A2;C2;"1";FEVEREIRO!A2;C2;"1") to count only Mondays, and how can it be fixed?

Tags: google-sheets, countif, unique-values

When using the formula =NETWORKDAYS.INTL(JANEIRO!A2;C2;"1";FEVEREIRO!A2;C2;"1") to count only Mondays in the January and February columns A and C sheets, I'm encountering an error. What is causing this error, and how can I modify the formula to correctly count only Mondays within the specified date range? Are there any formatting or syntax requirements that need to be met when using the NETWORKDAYS.INTL function?

I only want to count Monday from the JANUARY, FEBRUARY, columns A and C sheets. But it is giving error in the formula:

= NETWORKDAYS.INTL (JANEIRO! A2; C2, "1"; FEVEREIRO! A2; C2, "1 ")
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RxMJd.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CIiA5.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A5X85.png)

Comment: @Glaucco You have not clarified how "to count only Sunday"; please edit your question to provide an unambiguous explanation of what this means. In addition, please edit your spreadsheet to provide an example of a successful outcome. The example that is included on sheet "DADOS" in your spreadsheet is flawed: June is counted twice; the calculation does not include "1" when it is part of a cell value (such as January, Row 5); and it does not count only on Sunday.

Comment: about the function = ArrayFormula (countif (split (join (","; $ A $ 4: $ A $ 200); ","); {D4: D56})) when the cell is empty, the value 0 is entered, possible to cell is empty when it has no value?

Comment: @Glaucco Your new spreadsheet is a major change from your original question. It is your responsibility to provide information in your question rather than leave it to others to dig into your spreadsheet to find information. And this is to your advantage: you want as many people as possible to read your question and consider a solution; but if you leave it to users to find that information then many people will, to put it simply, not bother.

Comment: I will change my question to make it easier to understand

Comment: Tedinoz, includes 3 images for easy understanding

Comment: @Glaucco You replaced your old question; you didn't supply an example of a successful outcome; the screenshots don't align to your question; you are using `NETWORK.INTL, which requires **two** dates, but there is only one date column (Column C) on each sheet; the role of Column A is still unclear; without explanation, your focus has moved from Sunday to Monday. I respectfully suggest that read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask); that you delete this question and create a new one, and provide a copy of your spreadsheet and example of a successful outcome.

Answer (score 0):

can you help me? I made the change to the question and the image to make it easier to understand